# More idiomatic BASH script for multi-folder file rename

Tags: bash, rename, idioms

I'm currently using a bunch of one-liners to rename generated icon files in bash.

```
for f in black/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_black.png" ; done
for f in blue/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_blue.png" ; done
for f in brown/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_brown.png" ; done
for f in green/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_green.png" ; done
for f in grey/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_grey.png" ; done
for f in red/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_red.png" ; done
for f in white/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_white.png" ; done
for f in yellow/*.png ; do mv $f "${f%%.png}_yellow.png" ; done
```

but boy is it long-winded. Given the folder structure, is there a single-line version I could be using that's more idiomatically BASH? I just want to know if I'm missing a trick.

I'm running on a Mac OS X Darwin command line, so no `rename` and no `prename` :-( and would prefer it in pure bash.

-- EDIT

So it doesn't get lost in the comments - Tim Zimmerman's answer worked as a one liner:

```
for d in */; do for f in $d*.png ; do mv "$f" "${f%%.png}_${d%%/}.png" ; done ; done
```

The doing a second rename in `${f%%.png}_${d%%/}.png` was a trick that had me stumped.

Comment: Yes, I could, except as mentioned in the question there does not appear to a `rename` on a vanilla MacOS X Darwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through all subdirectories in a loop and use the name of the directory again for renaming the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */; do
    for f in "$d"*.png; do
        mv "$f" "${f%%.png}_${d%%/}.png"
    done
done
```

Note, that `$d` contains the `/`, so it has to be removed on renaming.

Comment: The array isn't really useful since you only reference it once. `for d in black blue brown green grey red white yellow; do`...

Comment: So given that I'm in the parent folder I could use  a `do for d in \`ls -p | grep /\`` ?

Comment: You are correct to use globs; do not parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: You can just use `for d in */; do` to ensure you are iterating over directories only. There's no need for the `if` statement.

Comment: Like @chepner said, do not parse the output of `ls` (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). However, you can test for directories. I updated my answer to go through all subdirectories of the current directory.

Comment: @chepner Looks good - but of course when I tried `for c in */; do for f in $c*.png ; do mv "$f" "${f%%/.png}_$c.png" ; done ; done` the extra `/` at the end of $c made the rename fail - `mv: rename yellow/arrow_up.png to yellow/arrow_up_yellow/.png: No such file or directory`

Comment: @TimZimmermann - perfect. Using as a one-liner: `for d in */; do for f in $d*.png ; do mv "$f" "${f%%.png}_${d%%/}.png" ; done ; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
for c in black blue brown; do
  for f in $c/*.png ; do mv "$f" "${f%%.png}_$c.png" ; done
done
```

or

```
for f in {black,blue,brown}/*.png; do mv "$f" "${f%%.png}_${f%/*}.png" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never have subdirectories with `*.png` files except the ones you will want to move, you can do

```
for f in */*.png; do
    d=${f%/*}
    b=${f#*/}
    mv "$f" "${b%.png}_$d.png"
done
```

If you are not hellbent on your current naming convention, you could even do

```
for f in */*.png; do
    mv "$f" "${f/\//_}"
done
```

which is not hard to turn into an actual one-liner if you want to.
(So this is basically replacing the first slash with an underscore.)